# How to make Bootstrap look more "Compact"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the same "Compact" look - in terms of `font-size`, `padding` and general use of space as I get when I use the browser zoom-out (Ctrl--). Of course without the side-effects most importantly reduction in container width.

I have tried fiddling with the `@baseFontSize` and `@baseLineHeight` variables in Bootstrap's http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html download screen but I am missing something as the result :

1. Doesn't look right - in terms of balance, padding is not right.
2. Breaks on the projector screen (the horror!) - select boxes, layout, everything goes crazy.

Please bail me out!

Comment: If I understand your question right, on zooming out, you want to keep text behaving as-is but also keep container's width the same? It's obvious that zoom out will reduce width of the container, except if you're using 100% width or adapting size using javascript (look Google drive). I recommend providing webpage or a fiddle and explain what you want to achieve on a actual project.

Comment: @maremp I mentioned the browser zoom-out because it closely correlates with the desired end-result i.e. decreasing the size content as well as space (padding in fields, table cells etc) while keeping the correct proportions. As solutions go, I was hoping to do this in CSS and not in Javascript as I am in essence not looking for dynamism. This is why I haven't posted a fiddle. Thanks for your comment though, it has allowed me to bring more clarity to the table (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

What about using media queries inside your html tag and using rem units based off it? Might be too late to start that but I find it a hand way to control spacing,

```
html{
    background: $black;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
        @media screen and (min-width: 2560px){
                font-size:16px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2559px){
                font-size:15px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1681px) and (max-width: 1919px){
                font-size:15px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1441px) and (max-width: 1680px){
                font-size:13px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1440px){
            font-size:13px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1365px){
            font-size:12px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
            font-size:12px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
            font-size:12px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:441px) and (max-width:767px) {
                font-size:12px;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:351px) and (max-width:440px) {
                font-size:12px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width:350px) {
                font-size:12px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if this is a problem related to the responsive style sheet. It is hard to give a definitive answer without knowing if you are working with or without the responsive style sheet. But if you are, the layout will not stay in proportion to a larger screen because it is responsive. So, if you do have that style sheet on, try removing it.

Comment: When I say it breaks on the projector screen, I mean the individual components and not the overall layout. For instance, fiddling the baseFontSize will make the inputs look strange as the text is no longer vertically center aligned. If I then fiddle with baseLineHeight, the text gets to be right but the arrow on the right side of select boxes breaks.

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap Table Compact**

```
 table-sm
    To reduce the cell padding on your tables add a class .table-sm to your Bootstrap table. 
    Example below
    
    <table class="table table-sm">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have two suggestions.

First, are you using Bootstrap 2.3.2 per your link above? You may be able to more easily solve your problems by using the new scaffolding that boostrap 3.0 (and up) has. It is kinda a pain to upgrade your site, but there are automatic converters, and the new system is MUCH better to work with, and might help.

Second, another CSS trick you should look into is font-weight and line-height. Font-weight can make your text thinner/thicker (grades are 100, 200, 300, 400, etc...). You might be able to make the font thinner, the lineheight lower, but the overall font bigger, which would "compact" things. If you didn't know it's worth trying.

```
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 30px;
```

Comment: No. the font-weight and line-height combination does not produce the desired effect.